# How can I speed up insert to Azure Table storage?

Tags: azure-storage

I implemented some of the code as described in [How to use the Table Storage Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/). I created a loop around the insert operation to insert several records, I do not want to do the batch insert. I find the insert operation to be very slow, not more than 6 records pr. second are inserted. The code is running on a virtual machine in azure, in the same subscription that contains the storage service. Does anyone know a faster way to insert records? We will periodically in our system have a continuous need for saving at least 100 records pr. second.

Part of my code is here:

```
   public void InsertCustomer(string tableName, CustomerEntity customer)
    {

        // Create the table client.
        CloudTableClient tableClient = _azureQueueStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

        //Get table reference
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);

        // Create the TableOperation that inserts the customer entity.
        TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(customer);

        // Execute the insert operation.
        table.Execute(insertOperation);
    }
```

---

Thanks Pascal. But for some reason, not described here, I do not want to do the batch insert. Do you know if the normal insert as described in my code is supposed to be this slow? The Customer object inserted is very simple:

```
 public class CustomerEntity : TableEntity
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public CustomerEntity(string lastName, string firstName)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = lastName;
        this.RowKey = firstName;
    }

    public CustomerEntity() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can batch the insert operation as long as your `customer` share the same PartitionKey

Just check the section on [How to: Insert a batch of entities](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/#insert-batch)